# How to import something globally (only once) in a React Project

Tags: reactjs, lodash

In my React project, I heavily depend on **lodash**. Now in each file I have an import statement like this

```
import each from 'lodash/each';
import compact from 'lodash/compact';
```

Is there any way in React that I don't need to import these in every file ? Can I import them once in App.jsx (The root component) and they would be available for all React Components that are it's children ?

Or maybe make lodash object globally available throughout the project ?

Answer (score 4):

This is not really recommended, but you could do this in your main file:

```
 import _ from 'lodash';
 window._ = _;
```

to make it available via global window object.

However, it would be better to configure your bundler or compiler setup to expose this as global variable.

Comment: Can you tell me how to configure bundler to expose lodash as a global variable ? I'm using webpack right now.

Comment: Use the expose-loader: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out. Thanks mate!