# import components for the whole project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to import a component one time and use it everywhere in react project?

For example I have multiple files:

File1.js:

```
import {comp} from '../reuse/comp.js'
....
```

File2.js:

```
import {comp} from '../reuse/comp.js'
....
```

File3.js:

```
import {comp} from '../reuse/comp.js'
....
```

App:

```
function App() {
    return <div>
              <File1 />
              <File2 />
              <File3 />
           </div>
}
```

and this is my structure:

```
-proj
  |---src
       |--- components
       |      |-- File1.js
       |      |-- File2.js
       |      |-- File3.js
       |-- app.css
       |-- app.js
       |---reuse
       |     |-- comp.js
```

How can I import once the `comp.js` in the `app.js` and use it everywhere?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186715/how-to-import-something-globally-only-once-in-a-react-project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import something globally (only once) in a React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186715/how-to-import-something-globally-only-once-in-a-react-project)

Comment: It is not a good solution for importing a react componont. I can't use the tag <> with the window variable

Comment: If you register your component in the window object in the project root, then in every file you should be able to do `const {MyComp} = window; /*...and use it with jsx template */ <MyComp />`. Why this couldn't be a solution ? (I think you don't even need to extract it explicitely from `window`)

Comment: One more downside is, that registering the component in the `window` only works on the client side. If you plan to have server side render it would fail. Although I'd advise against importing "globally," a component should only be loaded when it's necessary for the code.